# Firebase queryorderedbykey().observe behind proxy

Tags: ios, firebase, proxy, firebase-realtime-database

Im working in a company, with having some Proxy security policies.

I have set an change observer on certain node in my firebase. see below code

```
func connectObserver(_ base_url:String) {

    fireBaseRefAppSettings = FIRDatabase.database().reference(fromURL: "\(base_url)")

    firebaseQueryHandler = fireBaseRefJamesAppSettings!.queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value, with: {
        snapshot in


        print("in queryOrderedByKey observe block"); // its not printing . I have set breakpoints here also. It looks its not coming inside this block.

        // I have checked this without proxy , its working fine.
        // My question is, What I have to do to work this behind the proxy

        if let jamesapp_settings_raw_data = snapshot.value as? NSDictionary{
           print("jamesapp_settings_raw_data \(jamesapp_settings_raw_data)")
        }

   }

}
```

Also I have seen the question, [Firebase notification not received behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40133703/firebase-notification-not-received-behind-proxy)

- My, next step is to open the ports recommended by the firebase docs i.e 5228, 5229, and 5230, lets see this works

If you have any info regarding this. please do comment and answer

Thanks

**Update 1**

I said to our IT Admin and he opened the ports 5228, 5229, and 5230 but it still not going in my code block mentioned above. :(

Comment: Did you verify you can write data to Firebase? i.e. setValue on a node then log into the Firebase web console and see if the updated data is there?