# How can i find my URL to connect to firebase?

Tags: android, firebase

I have created an application that connects to the Firebase realtime database.
The application works properly, but on the mobile phones where it is installed, the internet access is restricted by URL.
It means that the internet data connection is restricted by the company. The APN has only a whitelist with some URLs.
How can I know which URL the application has access to in order to connect to Firebase?
Thank you.

Comment: *"internet access is restricted by URL"* - Could you say more about exactly what this restriction is about? I've never heard of this before.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the internet data connection is restricted by the company. The APN has only a whitelist with some URLs.

Comment: Realtime Database requires a direct websocket connection to the URL you see in your google-services.json file.  You might not be able to whitelist this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is your company using a proxy server?

If yes, there is already post about this, [Firebase notification not received behind proxy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40133703/firebase-notification-not-received-behind-proxy)