# Receiving Firebase Notifications behind a corporate firewall (with NAT)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, firewall, nat

I am deploying a corporate Android app that receives firebase notifications in my corporate network. Devices in the corporate network use a Proxy, Firewall and NAT (many to one) to access the Internet.
How do I setup the firewall to allow these android devices to receive the notifications?

[I have no issue in accessing Google's FCM to send the notifications. The issue is that the notifications are not received in the devices]

Comment: answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40133703/firebase-notification-not-received-behind-proxy